# How can I define starting position of glutWireCube?

Tags: c++, graphics, glut

I am rather new to programming so I may not use the correct terminology. I am trying to create a dog out of only glutwirecubes, however I cannot figure out how to define a starting position for the back legs, nor can I figure out how to close the space between my 'shoulder' and 'elbows'.  I have each body part assigned to rotate by key press. I also realize that my use of glPushMatrix and glPopMatrix may not be correct as I do not fully understand how the matrix stack is saved/loaded.

```
    glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-1, 0, 0);
glRotatef((GLfloat)body,1, 0, 0);//sets rotations about x,y,z axis
glTranslatef(1, 0, 0);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(2.0, 0.4, 0.5);//sets dimensions of cube
glutWireCube(2.0);//sets scale of wire cube
glPopMatrix();

glPopMatrix();

glPushMatrix();
glTranslatef(-1, 0, 0);
glRotatef((GLfloat)shoulder, 0, 0, 1);//sets rotations about x,y,z axis
glTranslatef(1, 0, 0);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(1.5, 0.4, 0.5);//sets dimensions of cube
glutWireCube(.75);//sets scale of wire cube
glPopMatrix();

glTranslatef(1,0,0);
glRotatef((GLfloat)elbow,0,0,1);//sets rotations about x,y,z axis
glTranslatef(1,0,0);
glPushMatrix();
glScalef(1.5,0.4,0.5);//sets dimensions of cube
glutWireCube(.75);//sets scale of wire cube
glPopMatrix();

glPopMatrix();
glutSwapBuffers();
```

The picture is the position I am aiming for, however my cubes always start oriented horizontally.

[image: glut sample]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with glTranslate right before, as for its friends !

For instance you might translate so that the center is now at the corner, so that your rotations rotate around this new handle.